# Rails 5 - Routing with custom slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to find a way to register a route for this following format:

```
https://example.com/zombies-killed-in-canada
https://example.com/zombies-killed-in-united-states
```

Example with pseudo code:

```
get '/zombies-killed-in-{:country}', to: 'search#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end it was quite easy:

```
get '/zombies-killed-in-:country', to: 'search#index'
```